# Swift 5, is it possible to factorize assignations

Tags: swift, swift5

Since SwiftUI and its ability to factorize methods into brackets (thanks to function builder) like so:

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello World!")
            Text("by Purple Giraffe").color(.gray)
        }

    }
```

*The function builder code is just here to emphasis the fact that factorizing can be handy. I don't expect it to help me doing factorized assignation.*

I was wondering if it was possible to factorize assignations (w/ something else) into brackets like so:

```swift
struct AnimationViewConfiguration {
    var contentMode:Int = 0
    var mainTitle:String = "test"
    var subTitle:String = ""
    var alternativeSubtitle:String = ""
    var numberOfIteration:Int = 0
    var frameRate = 40
    var maximumSimultaneousParalax:Int = 5
    var minimumSimultaneousParalax:Int = 2
}

class someViewController: UIViewController {
    var mainBackgroundAnimationViewConfig = AnimationViewConfiguration()

    func animateBackground(_ useAlternativeBackground:Bool) {
        // The normal bulky way
        if useAlternativeBackground == false {
            mainBackgroundAnimationViewConfig.contentMode = 3
            mainBackgroundAnimationViewConfig.mainTitle = "Your super animation"
            mainBackgroundAnimationViewConfig.subTitle = "A subtitle anyway"
            mainBackgroundAnimationViewConfig.alternativeSubtitle = "Hey another one!"
            // partial or complete assignation
            // mainBackgroundAnimationViewConfig.numberOfIteration = 4
            mainBackgroundAnimationViewConfig.frameRate = 40
            mainBackgroundAnimationViewConfig.maximumSimultaneousParalax = 19
            mainBackgroundAnimationViewConfig.minimumSimultaneousParalax = 3
        } else {
            // The way I'd like it to be
            mainBackgroundAnimationViewConfig with { // imaginary `with` keyword
                contentMode = 0
                mainTitle = "Your super animation"
                subTitle = "A subtitle anyway"
                alternativeSubtitle = "Hey another one!"
                // partial or complete assignation
                // numberOfIteration = 4
                frameRate = 40
                maximumSimultaneousParalax = 19
                minimumSimultaneousParalax = 3
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The whole point would be to avoid repeating long variable name 15 times, knowing that you often do this with already 2,3,4 indenting (which makes it even more annoying **to grab an eye on**).

For people proposing to put it in a specific function, I'd say that for the same reasons we sometimes use anonymous functions (i.e. used only once...), it would still be convieniant to do the assignation without making more boilerplate too.

---

Thanks @matt for mentioning the `with` keyword used for this purpose in other languages~

If it doesn't exist, is it comming in swift5.1+?

Wouldn't you find it handy?

Comment: You can take a look at this example: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/pull/1047/files , it makes html declaratively available in swift with use of blocks, function builders and property wrappers, same as SwiftUI.

Comment: No it is not coming, as I've already told you. — Why isn't your new example covered by my first answer? You can initialize an AnimationViewConfiguration with _only the properties you want to change_ from the defaults. My first answer looks _exactly_ like your `with` construct.

Comment: Don't really understand why I've got a -1 tho 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> wouldn't you find it handy?

No. What’s wrong with

```
var test = Test(
                a : 3,  
                c : 4, 
                s : "hey" 
            )
```

to start with? This leaves the *other* properties at their default values.

Or, if you mutate later,

```
test.c = 4
test.a = 3
test.s = "hey"
```

Or

```
(test.c, test.a, test.s) = (4, 3, "hey")
```

? I don’t see how another layer of syntactic sugar is desirable. 
There are languages that use a `with` construct that does the sort of thing you describe (distributing properties over a single reference instead of explicit dot notation every time), but I don’t yearn for it in Swift.

---

Edit after your edit: If it is merely the long *name* you object to, copy to a short-named temp variable, set the desired properties, and copy back:

```
var thisIsAReallyLongName = Whatever()
do {
    var temp = thisIsAReallyLongName
    temp.c = 4
    temp.a = 3
    temp.s = "hey"
    thisIsAReallyLongName = temp
}
```

Comment: did you check the new feature of Swift? :-) (i updated my answer with citation) it will allow us to write incomprehensible code ... Ach, jaj ...

Comment: I oversimplified the example and lost the point of my question. I'll edit the question to make it clearer. Tho you got it while mentioning `with`, could you tell me from which language you were speaking of?

Comment: @itMaxence I've used so many languages and have forgotten them, so I don't remember which languages used `with` in this way. But I've already said Swift doesn't have this and has no plans to, and I've shown you the existing alternatives, so I don't see how revising the question would add anything.

Comment: For the sake of clarity I'd say. With this new exemple I really see how my eyes would far more easily parse the bulky assignations. But yeah there is nothing to be done at the moment appart from doing the workaround you edited. Thanks for your time anyway 

Answer (score 1):

closest to what you want is

```
struct Test {
    var a:Int = 0
    var b:Int = 0
    var s:String = ""
    mutating func update(_ closure: (inout Int, inout Int, inout String)->Void)->Void {
        closure(&a, &b, &s)
    }
}

var test = Test()

test.update { (a, b, c) in
    a = 10
    b = 20
    c = "Alfa"
}
```

or better (supporting partial update, and xcode gives you what is avaiable)

```
struct Test {
    var a:Int = 0
    var b:Int = 0
    var s:String = ""
    mutating func update(_ closure: (inout Self)->Void)->Void {
        closure(&self)
    }
}

var test = Test()

test.update { (v) in
    v.a = 20
    v.s = "Alfa"
}
```

UPDATE: who knows the future?

> Swift New Features
>
> You can call values of types that declare func
>   callAsFunction methods like functions. The call syntax is shorthand
>   for applying func callAsFunction methods.

```
struct Adder {
    var base: Int

    func callAsFunction(_ x: Int) -> Int {
      return x + base
    }
}

var adder = Adder(base: 3)
adder(10) // returns 13, same as 
adder.callAsFunction(10)
```

> You must include func callAsFunction argument
>   labels at call sites. You can add multiple func callAsFunction methods
>   on a single type, and you can mark them as mutating. func
>   callAsFunction works with throws and rethrows, and with trailing
>   closures. (59014791)

Comment: I updated my question to make it clearer. +1 for mentionning this swift evolution tho, it looks really cool 

Comment: I am not so happy, as you are. Such a syntactic sugar could very easily lead to "very hard to read" code, where the functionality is hidden and and worst, it could be different from case to case, even though the syntax looks equal..

Comment: unfortunately, (see my updated answer) in next swift release it will be legal to see exactly, what he wants aka test { a = 10, b = 20, c = "something else" } (replace , with newline). it looks very terrible for me.

Comment: Mhmm, I get your point for this evolution, since having hidden code often leads to abuse and less understandable behaviour. Though my point is to **factorize the variable name** to **only** explicitly list/assign _some_ or all of its properties. It should not need more code/function/anything to work. So I don't see how my goal relates this feature, or maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Could you edit your example to include how you would be able to write `test { \n a = 10 b = 20 \n c = "something else" \n } `. In the end having to write a `callAsFunction...` for each and every properties would be more painfull than simply make a specialized assignation function then ‍♂️

Comment: func callAsFunction works with throws and rethrows, and with trailing closures

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem myself, that's how I found your question (sorry if you've moved on since then).

I first thought SwiftUI would suggest an answer, but all it seems to do for assignments is chain methods together: `Text.color(:)` from your example (actually it didn't work so I had to change it into `Text.foregroundColor(:)`) is a method that returns a new Text instance with the new color, and `color` may not even be a property of the struct as it seems to be backed by an undocumented `modifiers` array that contains `SwiftUI.Text.Modifier.color(Optional(gray))` after running your example.

So your strict requirements got me thinking, and in the end I found a rather simple workaround which involves adding a single (public) `change(:)` method to your struct:

```swift
mutating func change(_ closure: (inout AnimationViewConfiguration) -> Void) {
        closure(&self)
    }
```

This will allow the following syntax, which I believe is quite close to our requirements:

```swift
var mainBackgroundAnimationViewConfig = AnimationViewConfiguration()

mainBackgroundAnimationViewConfig.change {
    $0.contentMode = 0
    $0.mainTitle = "Your super animation"
    $0.subTitle = "A subtitle anyway"
    $0.alternativeSubtitle = "Hey another one!"

    // partial or complete assignation
    // numberOfIteration = 4
    $0.frameRate = 40
    $0.maximumSimultaneousParalax = 19
    $0.minimumSimultaneousParalax = 3
}
```

Unless I'm missing something, this should work… Sure, you can run arbitrary code in there, and you will need to explicitly refer to `self` at the caller site if needed; and there may be some caveats with retain cycles one needs to look out for, but at first glance, I don't see anything beyond standard closure caveats. But please do point out any issues you may find!

Obviously, this version only works with mutable properties: trying to change a `let` constant won't compile, whether the struct itself is the constant, or any of its properties. For the former case, you can return a modified copy instead:

```swift
func copyWithChanges(_ closure: (inout AnimationViewConfiguration) -> Void) -> AnimationViewConfiguration {
    var copy = self
    closure(&copy)
    return copy
}

// call it like this:

let newVersionOfTheConfig = mainBackgroundAnimationViewConfig.copyWithChanges {
    $0.contentMode = 12
    // etc.
}
```

For classes, whether they're vars or constants, it's even simpler (if we're still assuming that all of their properties are mutable) since the closure will get a reference to the instance that it can modify at will:

```swift
func change(_ closure: (AnimationViewConfiguration2) -> Void)  {
    closure(self)
}
```

**EDIT:** As of [Swift 5.2](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0253-callable.md), you can name the `change(_:)` function `callAsFunction(_:)` and save some typing on the call site:

```swift
// inside the struct declaration:
mutating func callAsFunction(_ closure: (inout AnimationViewConfiguration) -> Void) {
        closure(&self)
    }
// ...
// using the struct:

var mainBackgroundAnimationViewConfig = AnimationViewConfiguration()

mainBackgroundAnimationViewConfig {
    $0.contentMode = 0
    $0.mainTitle = "Your super animation"
    $0.subTitle = "A subtitle anyway"
    $0.alternativeSubtitle = "Hey another one!"
}
```

**End edit**

However, if you'd want to use this syntax for initializing an instance, or for making a copy with new values for any of its immutable properties, I honestly don't see any way of accomplishing that, even if we tried to re-implement immutability with "delayed initialization" property wrappers ([example use case in the proposal for the feature](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0258-property-wrappers.md#delayed-initialization))  but that seems to be out of scope: we only ever mentioned already-initialized instances and mutable properties here.

Comment: You're the closest from what I had in mind. It's a pitty it's not a feature of Swift yet (who knows). Thanks for your input it's cool!

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer! Edited to fix a problem (removed superfluous return type), and I also added a way to remove the function call by using the "Callable values of user-defined nominal types" evolution in Swift 5.2: now we can call the instance itself as a function, which may be handy here…

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting a bit confused. There's several concepts at play here and function builders don't play quite as nicely as you might think with the rest of it.

When code is placed between 2 braces, we call it a **block** of code. This is a good way to help organise our programs, because we can place related pieces of sequential logic together. The most common place for a block of code to appear is in a function. For example, I have a function that calculates a user's salary:

```swift
func calculateSalary() {
   let monthly = 3500
   let yearlyTotal = monthly * 12
   print("Your salary is \(yearlyTotal)")
}
```

Then we can **call** the function like so:

```swift
calculateSalary()
```

But, we can also assign this function to a variable, where we refer to it as a **closure**. (Functions and closures are actually exactly the same thing, functions are just named closures that we can easily reuse and call).

```swift
let calculateSalary: () -> Void = {
   let monthly = 3500
   let yearlyTotal = monthly * 12
   print("Your salary is \(yearlyTotal)")
}
```

As you would expect, we can call the function in the exact same way.

This means we can pass closures as parameters to methods or initialisers, so that another function or initialiser can call our function that we pass in. For example:

```swift
/** 
 * this is a stupid, pointless class (but it demonstrates
 * closures-as-parameters nicely)
 */

class SalaryCalculator {

    let closure: () -> Void

    init(closure: () -> Void) {
        self.closure = closure
    }

}

let calculator = SalaryCalculator(closure: {
   let monthly = 3500
   let yearlyTotal = monthly * 12
   print("Your salary is \(yearlyTotal)")
})

// call the closure!
calculator.closure()
```

This can also be written using **trailing closure** syntax, where we can remove the argument label if the closure is the last parameter to our initialiser (or function):

```swift
let calculator = SalaryCalculator {
   let monthly = 3500
   let yearlyTotal = monthly * 12
   print("Your salary is \(yearlyTotal)")
}

// call the closure!
calculator.closure()
```

This is what you are seeing when the code appears to be encapsulated in braces (*factorize* is not a term that is used to describe this). It's actually a closure parameter being passed to the initialiser of the underlying type.

Function builders in SwiftUI use this same principal, but it's a bit more subtle and complex than I'd like to get into right now.

**So**, to answer your question more directly–if you'd like to break your code up into more manageable pieces, I'd create a `class` or `struct` that encapsulates some logic, then break up the sequentially related calls into functions on that new `class` or `struct`. I'm not sure why you would want to be doing assignments in the manner shown in your question, it doesn't really make sense especially with Swift's initialisers providing so much customisability anyway.

Comment: I updated my question, the whole goal is to be able to make bulky assignation without having to repeat x time the sometime-really-long-name of a variable

Comment: @itMaxence You're probably best off creating a method on the object with all these changes. Then you can just use `self.` (or no prefix) to refer to the properties.

Comment: At the moment you're right, but for the same reason we sometimes make a one-use-only anonymous closure, it could be handy to avoid having a one-time-assignation function

Comment: @itMaxence There isn't really a solution for that at the moment. The best I can recommend is using shorter variable names.